# Vim Textmate fuzzyfinder showing abbreviated paths

Tags: vim, textmate, macvim, fuzzyfinder

I'm using the fuzzyfinder_textmate "plugin" on vim (macvim, actually).

It works fine, except that when I search for a file, it gives me ***abbreviations*** for the paths

For example,

```
1: a/v/b/index.html.haml
2: a/v/a/index.html.haml
```

Is there a way to configure fuzzyfinder_textmate to show me the full-paths when I search?

like this?

```
1: app/views/basic_search/index.html.haml
2: app/views/advanced_search/index.html.haml
```

Answer (score 1):

I have heard quite a few complaints about fuzzyfinder. I would recommend you use Command-T plugin by Wincent which can be found [here](https://github.com/wincent/Command-T). It displays path by default the way you have mentioned.